# Inputbox focus set style to containing div : Background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this page `div#container` which contains inputboxes, textareas and selectboxes. When I click them i want to change the background color of the containing div "djform_field"

```
#dj-classifieds .dj-additem .djform_row .djform_field:focus {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

<div class="djform_field">
        <textarea id="contact" name="contact" rows="1" cols="55" class="inputbox required"><?php echo $this->item->contact; ?></textarea>     
         <div id="input-tips"><span class="hint"><?php echo JTEXT::_('COM_DJCLASSIFIEDS_CONTACT_TOOLTIP')?><span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span></div>             
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I used THIS -> `<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".djform_row :input").on('click',function() {
      $(".djform_field").css("background","red");});
   });
   $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".djform_row :input").on('blur',function() {
      $(".djform_field").css("background","yellow");});
   });
 </script>` But, It makes ALL the INPUTS RED ! I only want to change background to the one I am at...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#contact').focus(function(){
  $('.djform_field').addClass('red');
}).blur(function(){
 $('.djform_field').removeClass('red');
})
```

See demo [here](http://jsbin.com/Ekufiwo/1/edit?html,css,js,output) (using jQuery)

Comment: What language is this beacouse it does not work on my site. I have to load the library. Tnx

Comment: jQuery. http://jsbin.com/Ekufiwo/1/edit   Add this into your page:
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` 

@user3057167 You can learn about jQuery here http://jquery.com .

Comment: Still does not work, i have also tried `<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".djform_row :input").on('click',function() {
      $(".djform_field").css("background","red");});
   });
 </script>`

Comment: @user3057167 It matters where you put the code. You should put jQuery and my code at the end of your page (just above </body>. And jQuery should be above the code.) If it does not work still, wrap my code with `$(function(){/*my code here*/});`
If it does not work yet, maybe you can paste your code into jsbin and copy the link to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.djform_field').children('*').click(function () { //use required selector in .children(), * means all children
    $('.djform_field').css('background', 'color');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Set one big click handler:

```
$("#container :text, #container select").click(function() {
    $("div.djform_field)".css("background-color", "red"); //or whatever
});
```